# The Component for route must be a react component even after exporting component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to React native and implementing react navigation but getting the component for route must be a react component  even i exported my component
I have check all related answer but all in vain.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import Launch from './Launch';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Launch);
```

Below is launch

```
import React from 'react';

import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator'

export default class Launch extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (      
      <AppNavigator></AppNavigator>       
    );
  }
}
```

App Navigator

```
//..........................       
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginScreen from './components/src/Login/LoginScreen'
import App from './components/src/App';

import Register from './components/src/Signup/Register';
import ViewPagerPage from './components/src/Settings/CPU/ViewPagerPage'

import TabIndicatorPage from './components/pages/TabIndicatorPage'
import TitleIndicatorPage from './components/pages/TitleIndicatorPage'



import {
    createStackNavigator,
    createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
    TabIndicatorPage: { screen: TabIndicatorPage },
    TitleIndicatorPage: {
        screen: TitleIndicatorPage, navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    ViewPagerPage: { screen: ViewPagerPage },
    Register: {
        screen: Register, navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    App: {
        screen: App,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    ViewPagerPage: { screen: ViewPagerPage },
    // Detail:{screen:Detail},
    // SecondScreen:{screen:SecondScreen},
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack);        

export default AppNavigator;
```

Here it is Login Controller giving error I also used export.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {View,ScrollView,KeyboardAvoidingView,Animated,ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,TextInput, KeyboardAwareScrollView,StyleSheet,Image,Easing,Text,AsyncStorage,ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';
import App from '../App';

import bgSrc from './images/wallpaper.png';
import logoImg from './images/logo.png';

import { NavigationActions,StackActions } from 'react-navigation'



import usernameImg from './images/username.png';
import passwordImg from './images/password.png';

import spinner from './images/loading.gif';
const MARGIN = 40;
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
```

//Login Controller

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component<{}> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { Login: false,showPass: true,
      press: false,
      isLoading: false,
      navigator:this.props.navigator,
      email:'',
```

Expected Login Screen should come

But I am getting red screen saying component must be react

Comment: I can't understand what is the expected results and what is the error

Comment: @Vencovsky Expected result Login Screen should come but in actual i am getting red screen saying the component must be react component

Comment: Please add the full code of login screen to your answer

Comment: Thanks @Vencovsky , Problem was 
import App from '../App';
This Line.I just removed the line and it's working .